# How to count multiple things from a big JOIN of tables

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I've always seen COUNT() used with * as argument and the GROUP BY determining what was meant to be counted, but i'm convinced you can count different things without having to do sub-queries, group by, then join (which is what I'm doing right now).

Let's build an example out of a simplified version of SO:

```
Table Question
idQuestion | title | idUser

Table Answer
idAnswer | idQUestion | text | idUser

Table Vote
idVote | idAnswer | type | idUser

Table Comment
idComment | idAnswer | text | idUser
```

To know how many comments and votes all answers have I'd do:

```
SELECT idAnswer, votes, comments FROM
   (SELECT idAnswer, count(*) AS votes FROM Answer A
       JOIN Vote B ON A.idAnswer=B.idAnswer
    GROUP BY idAnswer) AS X
JOIN
   (SELECT idAnswer, count(*) AS comments FROM Answer A
       JOIN Comment B ON A.idAnswer=B.idAnswer
    GROUP BY idAnswer) AS Y
ON X.idAnswer=Y.idAnswer
```

Can this be done without sub-selects? is anything achieved by avoiding them?

**how can you also count negative votes and positive votes on the same query?**

Comment: By the way, you're missing idAnswer for your vote table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT idAnswer, COUNT(DISTINCT VOTE.idVote), COUNT(DISTINCT comments)
FROM Answer 
LEFT JOIN COMMENT ON Answer.idAnswer = Comment.idAnswer
LEFT JOIN VOTE ON Answer.idAnswer = Vote.idAnswer
GROUP BY idAnswer
```

As for the second part of your question, thanks to Andriy M!

```
SELECT
  Answer.idAnswer,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN VOTE.type = 'up' THEN VOTE.idVote END) AS upvotes,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN VOTE.type = 'down' THEN VOTE.idVote END) AS downvotes,
  COUNT(DISTINCT comments) as comments
FROM Answer 
LEFT JOIN COMMENT ON Answer.idAnswer = Comment.idAnswer
LEFT JOIN VOTE ON Answer.idAnswer = Vote.idAnswer
GROUP BY Answer.idAnswer
```

Comment: You should use left joins. What if no comment has been left?

Comment: There is no such thing as a `left inner join` ;-) `left join` or `left outer join` are both correct.

Comment: Besides, you need to use `DISTINCT` on both `COUNT`s, since it's a many to many relationship (This would be ok if there were only one `LEFT JOIN`)

Comment: Thanks you Lamak. In any case, OP can see that it's very possible

Comment: @Cruncher hey! can you please also answer the question I've placed in bold?

Comment: @Daren difficult, I can give it a try

Comment: @Cruncher it works but looks weird... I also found Count(Case WHEN type = 'up' THEN 1 END) which i'm not sure if its better, the double join seems expensive.

Comment: @Cruncher if you beleiive so, can you please edit your answer to use it, mostly for having built between all the best possible answer... even though u get all the rep credit. :)

Comment: @Daren: When the VOTE table is joined only once, the CASEs need to be used like this: `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN VOTE.type = 'up' THEN VOTE.idVote END) AS upvotes`. (But if COMMENT wasn't used, your expression would work well.)

Comment: @Cruncher: The WHERE clause in your second query will result in **no output** for answers that have only upvotes or only downvotes or neither.

Comment: @AndriyM Should the last join be a FULL JOIN?

Comment: No, you just need to move both comparisons to the VOTE join conditions (each to the corresponding condition).

Comment: No, that would just yield wrong results for answers with both ups and downs. Shouldn't you test that yourself instead of asking me, though? :)

Comment: @AndriyM I did some testing, I like "COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN VOTE.type = 'up' THEN VOTE.idVote END) AS upvotes" the best. Do you mind if I put it in my answer?

Comment: No I don't, please feel free.

Comment: woaw, seems the question wasn't so simple after all, we finally got the perfect answer after more than 24h and 4 people correcting it... :)